# PG::UndefinedTable error with associated where clause in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Here is a very simple relationship which I am attempted to connect and run a `where` clause on. This worked fine in Rails 3, but is not longer working on Rails 4. The syntax all looks correct to me. All record relationships such as `listing.seller` or `seller.listings` all work as expected.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: "User"
end
```

However

```
Listing.joins(:seller).where({ seller: { id: 1 } })
# Or
Listing.eager_load(:seller).where({ seller: { id: 1 } })

# Both result in the following error:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "seller"
LINE 1: ...s" ON "users"."id" = "listings"."seller_id" WHERE "seller"."...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the where clause you have to use the actual table name. Since you're not following convention this issue comes up.

```
Listing.joins(:seller).where({ users: { id: 1 } })
# Or
Listing.eager_load(:seller).where({ users: { id: 1 } })
```